# Recurrence equation for sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I have the following question on a homework assignment and I'm not sure how to approach it

> Assume we have the following sorting algorithm:
>
> To sort an array of size N(A[1…N]), the algorithm will do the following:
>
> 1. Recursively, Sort the first N-1 elements A[1…N-1]
> 2. Use binary search to ﬁnd the correct place of A[N] to add it to the sorted list. After ﬁnding the correct place, it will need to shift the values to make place for A[N].
>
> Write the detailed recurrence equation for this algorithm (do not omit any terms).

Comment: While this community is built around programmers helping other programmers, I personally believe that this sort of question should be discouraged. Answer "sketches" may be more appropriate, but providing full-on solutions to what are clearly homework problems should **not** be encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

where `C` is some constant.

Let's see where each term comes from in the `n > 1` case:

- T_{n - 1}

> Recursively, Sort the first N-1 elements A[1…N-1]

- log n

> Use binary search to ﬁnd the correct place of A[N] to add it to the
>   sorted list

- n

> After ﬁnding the correct place, it will need to shift the values to make place for A[N].

Answer (score 1):

Let T(n) be the runtime of the algorithm described for an array of n elements. First, it recursively calls itself on the first n-1 elements, giving us a cost of T(n-1). Then, it uses binary search to find the position of the element at original position n, thus taking log(n-1) time. Finally, it shifts the elements (at most n-1 of them) to make space for the new one, which requires at most n steps.

Putting the pieces together, we get T(n) <= T(n-1) + log(n-1) + n - 1. Finally, since you did not specify the base case, I am assuming the algorithm just does nothing on an empty list (thus trivially sorting it) and then get T(0) = 0.